# Change cursor to image on hover: Hover events not always triggering

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to create an effect where if you hover over a text element, the cursor should change to an image and when you leave the text element the cursor should restore to a normal cursor. This is not working when I use React and normal CSS. The image lingers sometimes if I move the cursor diagonally or too quickly in and out of the container.

What I would like to achieve is this from (https://www.woodwood.com/en/):

[image]

Here is my broken code and a fiddle of the issue:
https://jsfiddle.net/smyL9v42/

```
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function TextWithCursor() {
  const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 })

  const handleMouseMove = event => {
    setCursorPosition({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY })
  }
  return (
    <div
      className="container"
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
    >
      HELLO
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608877906884-5ffef2ef9612?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&w=200&q=80"
        className="imageWithOpacity"
        alt="Custom cursor"
        style={{
          left: cursorPosition.x,
          top: cursorPosition.y,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <TextWithCursor />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: none;
}

.container:hover .imageWithOpacity {
  opacity: 1;
}

.imageWithOpacity {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

**Here is how it looks when it's broken:**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**pointer-events**

You can fix your code by adding `pointer-events: none;` to the hover image. This prevents the image from emitting mouse events, which is the cause of the problem. Reference: [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Run the snippet to understand how it works.

**React Snippet**

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function TextWithCursor() {
  const [isHovering, setIsHovering] = useState(false)
  const [cursorPosition, setCursorPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 })

  const handleMouseMove = event => {
    setCursorPosition({ x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY })
  }
  return (
    <div
      className="container"
      style={{
      }}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
    >
      HELLO
      <img
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1608877906884-5ffef2ef9612?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&w=200&q=80"
        className="imageWithOpacity"
        alt="Custom cursor"
        style={{
          position: "fixed",
          left: cursorPosition.x,
          top: cursorPosition.y,
        }}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <TextWithCursor />, document.getElementById('root') );
```

```css
.container {
  cursor: hidden;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: none;
}

.container:hover .imageWithOpacity {
  opacity: 1;
}

.imageWithOpacity {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```